# Is it safe to leave encrypted (FileVault) macOS as is when leaving a company?

Tags: macos, filevault

Last day at work.

I have a Mac Mini with Sierra on board. FileVault is turned on. Disk is fully encrypted and the OS is not linked to AppleID. Just a local user account.

Assuming that only I know the password to this account. Is it safe to leave that Mac as it is (I don't care about the content since it's already cleaned) or should I call `diskutil cs delete UUID` on an encrypted partition to wipe it and then do a clean installation from USB that I have?

In other words. Is it safe if I will simply shut it down for the last time without formatting?

Comment: In general, I would always advise wiping your disk before leaving/giving/selling a computer, just to get rid of personal information, but that's my take. Does the company have a standard protocol you're supposed to follow? It's possible that the company's IT department will wipe it anyway, in which case it won't matter.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "safe"? Nobody else able to access your data, company able to re-install the OS without you? Also, is this the only account on the Mac or are there other accounts (which can unlock FV) as well?

Comment: I am not so sure that I like this question because as written, it sounds like you want information/instructions/assurance for  locking the employer out of the the data created on a employer's computer which was created on the employer's time either through encryption or outright destruction. To put it in a non-digital analogy, would you burn all your files in your file cabinet prior to leaving?